# Possibility to have no spaces when creating a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iteration

For example, if I do this:

```
for i in '12345':
        print("Welcome",i,"times")
```

It outputs:

```
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
```

But I want it like this:

```
Welcome1times
Welcome2times
Welcome3times
Welcome4times
Welcome5times
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `print("Welcome" + i + "times")`

Comment: `print("welcome{}times".format(i))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, by using the `sep` parameter of the [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
for i in '12345':
    print("Welcome", i, "times", sep="")

>>>
Welcome1times
Welcome2times
Welcome3times
Welcome4times
Welcome5times
```

By the way, you should think about generating your string using standard string formating methods.
For example, you could do :

```
for i in '12345':
    print("Welcome%stimes"%i)
```

Or in a more python-3 way :

```
for i in '12345':
    print("Welcome{i}times".format(i=i))
```

Or even shorter (thanks @StefanPochmann)

```
for i in '12345':
    print(f"Welcome{i}times")
```

Comment: Or `print(f'Welcome{i}times')`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to select your answer!